# function-definition in function for C++

Tags: c++, g++, nested, pthreads

```
 void iter_threads(int start, int end, void (*func)(int n))
 {
   int n = start;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

   void *thread_body(void *ptr)
   {
     for (;;) {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
       int i = (n)++;
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
       if (i >= end)
         break;
       func(i);
     }
   }

   pthread_t thread_id[8];
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
     pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, thread_body, NULL);
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
     pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
 }
```

Hi guys, I know that g++ doesn't support nested function. Is it possible to convert this function into a non-nested one?

Comment: Yes, just move it outside of the enclosing function. go give it a try, we'll wait.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: If I move it outside, how do I get the value of 'end' and 'n'?

Comment: There's a reason the thread function takes a `void *`.

Comment: Create a structure containing the variables and pass it as the last argument to `pthread_create` and it will get passed as the argument to `thread_body`.

Comment: If you have a compiler that supports `lambda` functions, you could use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You move the thread function outside the enclosing function. You create a structure to hold the parameters it needs to do its job (`n` and `end`, in this case) and pass a pointer to that structure to the function, something on this general order:

```
struct params { 
    int n;
    int end;
    void (*f)(int);
};

void thread_body(void *param) { 
   params *p = (params *)param;

   for (;;) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       int i = (p->n)++;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
       if (i >= end)
           break;
       p->f(i);
    }
}
```

Unless you're using an *ancient* version of g++, however, that's really *not* want you want to do at all. You almost certain want to use the threading support built into the C++11 standard library. Using this, your task becomes almost trivial by comparison. Virtually all the syntactic overhead of threading just disappears. Better still, there's a pretty fair chance that (e.g., by using an atomic int instead of an int protected by a mutex) it'll actually end up substantially more efficient as well.